# chrome browser not displaying radio buttons or select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Hi Ive got a bit of a weird problem all of a sudden my radio btns and select boxes are not displaying in chrome (ie,firefox works fine) Chrome used to work perfectly on my site but all of a sudden it just stopped displaying rad btns and selectboxes

I have combed over this code and tweaked it for hours but just cant find the error wil greatly appreciate it if someone else can have a look for a second opinion perhaps you will see something im missing

Thanks

[image]

[image]

```
 <label class="green">
     <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team1'].'" />
     <span>'.$team1.'</span>
     </label>
     <br />
     <br /> 
     <label class="yellow">
     <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="'.$row['team2'].'"/>
     <span>'.$team2.'</span>
     </label>
     <br />
   <br />
    <label class="pink">
    <input type="radio" name="picks['.$x.']" value="draw">
    <span>Draw</span>
    </label>
    <br />';
    echo'<b>BY</b>';
        echo'<select name="score[$x]" id="score[$x]">';
            echo'<option value="0">0</option>';
            echo'<option value="1">1</option>';
            echo'<option value="2">2</option>';
            echo'<option value="3">3</option>';
            echo'<option value="4">4</option>';
            echo'<option value="5">5</option>';
            echo'</option>';
```

Please let me know if I should add anything else

Comment: why it is tagged by js if no js here? But this looks like a css problem. Can you create any demo for us?

Comment: @daremachine even if I put somethig simple like this `<input type="radio" />` it does not get displayed so not a css problem

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee ok.. why you mean "even" its very wide

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee is helping me to find the error we have noticed if you make a radio button or select box without applying any css it is still not displaying which is weird

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/radio-button-doesnt-show-in-google-chrome):

Try adding this to your CSS file:

```
/* -- Radio Button Fix -- */
input[type="checkbox"] { -webkit-appearance: checkbox; }
input[type="radio"] { -webkit-appearance: radio; }
input[type="submit"], input[type="button"] { -webkit-appearance: button; }
select { -webkit-appearance:textfield; }
```

This [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033296/radio-button-and-checkbox-wonky-behavior-in-google-chrome) may also help.